# Simple proof about normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

> For a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$, prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> > a) $N$ is normal.
> >
> > b) Each left coset of $N$ is also a right coset. That is, for each $a\in G$, there is a $b\in G$ such that $aN=Nb$.
> >
> > c) For each $a\in G$, $aN=Na$.

I chose to take the route showing that *a* implies *c* and *c* implies *b*. I am now having trouble completing the proof cycle. I don't know how to show that *b* implies *a*. Any hints or help would be appreciated. Our definition of a normal subgroup is as follows.

$N$ is normal if for all $g$ in $G$, $gNg^{-1}=N$.

Comment: Hint: use or prove the fact that any two right cosets of $N$ are either disjoint or exactly equal (as sets).

Comment: I'm not seeing exactly how this helps me. I'm assuming I have to show that Nb=Na somehow, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: If you prove that fact, then it means to show that $Nb=Na$ it is enough to show that the intersection of $Na$ and $Nb$ is non-empty.